# Free online analysis engine?

Tags: analysis, engines, online

Is there an online analysis engine that allows you to enter a PGN and get a game analysis, showing where suboptimal moves were made?

I know there are programs for download/purchase that do this, but I specifically want an online one. The ones I've found ([e.g.](http://analyse.deep-chess.de/)) can analyze positions, but not entire games.

Comment: If you do this, the amount of CPU attention devoted to your position will be variable, and perhaps not enough to find a high quality solution.

Comment: I want this apps please because of its triks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[lichess.org](http://lichess.org) has played game analysis and allows you to edit a board before AI game.

Its analysis shows wrong and right moves and percentage statistics of mistakes for both sides.

Comment: But it doesn't seem possible to enter an existing game for analysis, only ones you've actually played on that site. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If PGN contains moves, you can copy it.
If it's not, I can just sorry.
Happy New Year)

Answer (score 8):

You can import your game on http://lichess.org/paste, then analyse it.

Answer (score 4):

http://analyse.deep-chess.de/ allows you to analyze your game online with different chess engines.

Comment: there is no way to enter PGN there, right? FEN is more than unclear...

Comment: btw, you can use some online PGN to FEN converter.

Comment: As of today, this site is dead.

Answer (score 4):

http://analysis.cpuchess.com/ analyses your game with an option of a variety of engines like houdini and stockfish

Answer (score 1):

I recently found that chess.com also has a free option to analyze an entire game (by pasting a PGN), although paid accounts can analyze in more detail.

https://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor (right panel, second tab)

The analysis process will intercalate comments idicating better moves if necessary. In the end, you will see a summary like this:

```
Strength        White   Black
-----------------------------
Excellent          41   38
Good               13   13
Inaccuracy (?!)     1    5
Mistake (?)         2    0
Blunder (??)        0    0
Forced              0    0
Best Move       66.7%    50.9%
Avg. Diff        0.14    0.19
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You can ask even very deep analysis, possibly also for whole games.

https://sites.google.com/site/distributedchess

Answer (score -2):

You may want to download this free Creatica chess game analyzer for Windows for your pgn games http://chessgame-analyzer.creatica.org/ Just right click on your pgn file and choose "Analyze with Stockfish". The result will be opened in your default pgn GUI; for example, in SCID vs PC or Chessbase.

Comment: Welcome to Chess Stack Exchange. You **must** state explicitly in your post that this is your own product: see [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Comment: Oh, and another thing: the question asks for an *online* solution, which this answer doesn't provide.