# Are there any free chess engines that can be used to analyze online or in a mobile phone?

Tags: engines

I want to analyze chess games. Is there any reliable chess engine that is free

Comment: Does this differ from https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4385/free-online-analysis-engine ?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify your mobile platform in your question.

On the iOS platform, I recommend my own apps for doing that. www.smallchess.com.

Otherwise, there're lots of possibilities. If you can narrow your focus, I'll edit my answer.