# Alternatives to the paid analysis on chess.com

Tags: beginner, websites

On chess.com we get only one full depth analysis in a day, which is very little. Is there a way to analyze more chess games and get all the accuracy metrics as well? Are there any other website which can help me do this analysis? This is because I want to analyze my games and learn from my mistakes.

Comment: lichess.org provides free analysis for signed up users (account is also free), but the metric is not accuracy in %, but rather a graph of the game evaluation and number of inaccuracies/mistakes/blunders and average centipawn loss (measure of precision compared to engine) for each player. Apart from that you can of course download Stockfish on your own computer and do analysis yourself. You can also import games you played on chess.com to lichess and let the server analyse them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free online analysis engine?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4385/free-online-analysis-engine)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lichess.org account you can analyze both games you played yourself there or games you imported. I think currently the limit is 25 of your games played in the site and (not 100% sure) half of that for games you did not play on the site, so either games from other players or ones that you imported.

Not sure exactly which stats you want however it gives you the number of blunders, mistakes and inaccuracies, as well as your average centi pawn loss which is a rough measure of how good your play was on average. Then you can for example use the "Learn from my mistakes" feature to see the positions where you made a mistake, and try to find a better move. Or you can simply look at the computer line in that position.